# CNN has ValueError: Error when checking target

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, mnist, conv-neural-network

I am using Fashion Mnist Dataset, but am new to CNN's. I am stuck on input matrix shape problem most probably.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers import Dense,Conv2D,Flatten,Dense,Dropout,MaxPool2D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Activation

dataset = pd.read_csv('fashion-mnist_train.csv')


X=dataset.iloc[:,1:].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,0].values
X=X/255.
X=np.reshape(X,(-1,28,28,1))
#input_shape_problem_i_think
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(28,28,1),filters=16,kernel_size=(3,3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Conv2D(filters=16,kernel_size=(3,3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=400,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=10,activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
#optimaztion
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,y,batch_size=100,epochs=1,validation_split=0.33,verbose=1,)
```

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_34 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_46 (Conv2D)           (None, 26, 26, 16)        160       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_40 (Batc (None, 26, 26, 16)        64        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_39 (Activation)   (None, 26, 26, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_39 (MaxPooling (None, 13, 13, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_47 (Conv2D)           (None, 11, 11, 16)        2320      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_41 (Batc (None, 11, 11, 16)        64        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_40 (Activation)   (None, 11, 11, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_40 (MaxPooling (None, 5, 5, 16)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_20 (Flatten)         (None, 400)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_35 (Dense)             (None, 400)               160400    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_18 (Dropout)         (None, 400)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_36 (Dense)             (None, 10)                4010      
=================================================================
Total params: 167,018
Trainable params: 166,954
Non-trainable params: 64
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Could you check y=dataset.iloc[:,0].values gives you a shape of (10,0) ?

Answer (score 0):

In your last layer you have 10 FC units, as you have 10 classes. So, you must send a one hot encoded verison of the labels. So, you can use to_categorical from keras.utils.

Labels : 0 - > One Hot Encoding: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Labels : 1 - > One Hot Encoding: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

You may need to change y slightly based on the format of your label.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers import Dense,Conv2D,Flatten,Dense,Dropout,MaxPool2D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.utils import to_categorical

dataset = pd.read_csv('fashion-mnist_train.csv')


X=dataset.iloc[:,1:].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,0].values

y = to_categorical(y, 10) # one hot encoded

X=X/255.
X=np.reshape(X,(-1,28,28,1))
#input_shape_problem_i_think
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(28,28,1),filters=16,kernel_size=(3,3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Conv2D(filters=16,kernel_size=(3,3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=400,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=10,activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
#optimaztion
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X,y,batch_size=100,epochs=1,validation_split=0.33,verbose=1,)
```